# Linux Alternative for MS KernRate

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, kernel

I'm looking for a way to examine a driver on Linux.
On Windows, I've been using KernRate which gives me CPU% over time.

What i'd like to know is CPU% and MemFootPrint per driver, like top but for drivers.

What utility should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

**man readprofile** may give some pointers.